# Looking for an ideas to implement dynamic column renaming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 143 column names in my df and 141 columns has same column format as shown below and want to update last 3 bytes of column name with month for columns starting with passengers or want to update whole column like '2009-jan' format based on targeted value

0: 'airport',
1: 'type of traffic',
2: 'Passengers 2009M01',
3: 'Passengers 2009M02',
4: 'Passengers 2009M03',
5: 'Passengers 2009M04',
6: 'Passengers 2009M05',
7: 'Passengers 2009M06',
8: 'Passengers 2009M07',
9: 'Passengers 2009M08',
10: 'Passengers 2009M09',
11: 'Passengers 2009M10',

Answer (score 0):

```py
import calendar
# df = your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,4],[3,5]], columns=['Passengers 2009M01', 'Passengers 2009M02'])

column_names = df.columns.to_list()
for each_column in column_names:
    if('Passengers' in each_column):
        dd = each_column.split(' ')[-1]
        year, month= dd.split('M')
        month = calendar.month_name[int(month)].lower()[:3]
        df.rename(columns={each_column: f'{year}-{month}'}, inplace=True)
```

output

```
   2009-jan   2009-feb
0   1         2
1   2         4
2   3         5
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I found it's best to put the renaming logic in a function and simply reassign the column names after passing each one through it. Like so:

```py
def column_renamer(col_name):
    # do some renaming, 
    # this just lower cases the name but you can do whatever
    return col_name.lower()


## then reassign the columns in the df

df.columns = [ column_renamer(col) for col in df.columns ]
```